# rails if result in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have a scope on my user model

I want to use this scope within a block on a view to display an option

my scope looks like this
`scope :can_own_project, where('superuser = ? OR projectadmin = ?', true, true)`

in my view I can achieve what I am looking to do by:

```
@stdprojectusers.each do |projectuser| %>
<% if (projectuser.superuser == true) || (projectuser.projectadmin == true) %>OPTION<%end%>`
```

what I would like to do is something like

```
<% if projectuser.can_own_project %> OPTION <% end %>
```

or

```
<% if projectuser == User.can_own_project %> OPTION <% end %>
```

any advise?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want a scope.  Scope's are applied to classes.  If I'm reading you right, you are working with an instance.  Is there a reason you can't simply define a method on that class?

```
class ProjectUser << ActiveRecord::Base

  def can_own_project?
    superuser == true || projectadmin == true
  end

end
```

Note, I changed your method and appended a '?'.  It's a habit of mine and isn't necessary, but I like the question form myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope should work, but performance will (over time) take a major hit.  What you'd want to do is:

```
<% if User.can_own_project.include?(projectuser) %> OPTION <% end %>
```

What I think you're looking for is a helper method...

```
module UserHelper

  def does_user_own_project?(user)
    user.superuser || user.projectadmin
  end

end
```

Your view could then look like:

```
@stdprojectusers.each do |projectuser| %>
  <% if does_user_own_project?(projectuser) %>OPTION<%end%>
```

If you'll want to use this outside the scope of this view, you could also make it an instance method on `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def does_user_own_project?
    self.superuser || self.projectadmin
  end

end
```